# How can I make JHipster applications REST services run on different docker containers?

Tags: docker, spring-boot, jhipster

I understand JHipster builds web application using spring boot based REST services. I would like to deploy various springboot services on different docker containers any idea how can such configuration be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the "[Spring Boot with Docker](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/)": it turns out the Dockerfile needed is quite straightforward

> let’s go ahead and create a Dockerfile in our Spring Boot project:

```
FROM java:8
VOLUME /tmp
ADD gs-spring-boot-docker-0.1.0.jar app.jar
RUN bash -c 'touch /app.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

> This Dockerfile is very simple, but that’s all you need to run a Spring Boot app with no frills: just Java and a JAR file.
>   The project JAR file is `ADD`ed to the container as "`app.jar`" and then executed in the `ENTRYPOINT`.